# Find certain words in tagfield values

Tags: extjs5

Extjs 5.

My app has a form with a tagfield with a list of over 200 items.

About 30 of these items contains the words 'another thing' (for example).
Each time I select one of these items should be dynamically added to the form an textareafield.

I tried several solutions without success, including using the match(), indexOf() and search() javascript methods.

```
onSelect : function (combo, records, eOpts) {
    var records = combo.getValue();
    for (var i = 0, count = records.length; i < count; i++) {
            while( records[i] == '%another thing%'){ //I know this is not the right way; Just to show what I'm looking for
                console.log('OK'); //logic...
                return;
            }
        }
  },
```

I would appreciate suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post an example on maybe [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home)?  Also, I'm not really sure what that while loop's purpose is... that looks odd.

Comment: Thank's for helping incutonez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
onSelect: function (field, records, opts) {
    // records parameter already contains all selected tags
    var found = Ext.Array.filter(records, function(r) {
        // conditions go here
        return r.get('text') === 'aardvark' || 
            r.get('text') === 'aardwolf';
    });
    // check if we found anything
    if (found.length > 0) {
        console.log(found);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wsm6an0n/2/

If you want to use wildcard like search, use `indexOf` instead of comparision:

```
onSelect: function (field, records, opts) {
    // records parameter already contains all selected tags
    var found = Ext.Array.filter(records, function(r) {
        // conditions go here
        return r.get('text').indexOf('aa') !== -1; // LIKE '%aa%'
    });
    // check if we found anything
    if (found.length > 0) {
        console.log(found);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rq90eLh4/1/

Comment: Thank's Krzysztof.
It was exactly what I was trying to accomplish.
It helped a lot.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof.

One more detail:
How can I remove the field added dynamically when I remove one of the items selected in tagfield?
Thanks again. Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lpb

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to use `beforedeselect` event. Also switching from `select` to `beforeselect` makes code simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/rq90eLh4/3/

Comment: Thank's again  Krzysztof. Excellent.